# Word request by description

Tags: word-request

What word conveys this description best?

Strong emotional disturbance, expressed in a short-term but violent mental reaction (rage, horror, despair, anger, etc.), during which consciousness and the ability to think are narrowed, and the ability to control one’s actions is weakened.

Also If I'm not mistaken there is spanish word as affectus

Comment: To the downvoters for "***Needs details or clarity***", please leave a comment with the details or clarity you think this question is missing which make it impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: @gotube well, usually for single word requests, an example of how  this word would fit in a given sentence would add a heck of a lot. I also fail to see what relevance the Spanish *affectus* has. If the OP provided detail, the question would be more useful for future visitors and not solely to Boyep.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider **meltdown**.

> A meltdown is an intense response to an overwhelming situation. It happens when someone becomes completely overwhelmed by their current situation and temporarily loses control of their behaviour.

[source](https://www.autism.org.uk/advice-and-guidance/topics/behaviour/meltdowns/all-audiences)

Edit

I add two more possibilities:

[apoplexy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apoplexy), which is on anger

> 2: a state of intense and almost uncontrollable anger

and **paroxysm**, which can refer also to other types of emotions:

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paroxysm)

> 2: a sudden violent emotion or action : OUTBURST

[CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paroxysm)

> a sudden and powerful expression of strong feeling, especially one that you cannot control

Comment: Somewhat informal still, much used in discussions related to neurodiversity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would depend on the nature of the emotion. If anger, I'd say "rage", or "irrational anger". If despair, I'd probably just say "despair".

If you're looking for a general phrase to describe any moment of loss of control from extreme emotion, I'd say "moment of irrationality" or "moment of unreasoning ". Or "period" if it lasted longer than a few minutes. If it's an emotion not normally associated with violence but where the person had a violent reaction is this case, I'd include the word "violent" or a similar word, like "moment of unreasoning, violent despair".

I don't know of one word for this. I see @seowjooping singapore suggest "meltdown", which is possible but I don't think quite what you're asking for. I take "meltdown" to mean a person demonstrates an extreme emotional reasponse. Like there's a classic video of a woman so upset that a candidate she didn't like won the election that she falls on her knees and screams "Nnnnnnoooooo!!!!!!" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDYNVH0U3cs) I'd call that a "meltdown", but she's not necessarily "losing consciousness" or out of control, and there's no indication that she became violent.

Answer (score 1):

## a rage

As a countable noun, "*a rage*" means what you describe, but only if it is brought on and mainly characterized by anger. Despair, for instance, cannot trigger or characterize a rage.

"meltdown" is a better answer, but I'm adding this for completeness

Answer (score 1):

We do need some clarity, because there are different terms used depending on how this mental state is expressed.

A common word to use when it is externally (physically) expressed is "outburst".

When the reaction is limited to an internal state, we use psychological terms, such as those used in traumatic disorders.

It sounds like you're describing a dissociative state, though it may also be an episode of de-realization or de-personalization, depending on exactly what is happening.

Since it is nearly impossible to explain an internal only state when your mind isn't working properly, this is a hard question to answer, even for a psychiatrist.